# WPF I cannot update a combobox value in code behind

Tags: wpf, combobox

I would want to update the following combobox selected item:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DictUsers, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectionChanged="ComboUser_SelectionChanged" SelectedValue="{Binding Edit.ProtLevel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The ItemsSource, DictUsers, comes from a dictionary:

```
DictUsers = new Dictionary<string, int>();
DictUsers.Add(string.Empty, 0); 
foreach (cUser user in App.Users)
    DictUsers.Add(user.Name, user.ShowLevel);
```

I cannot access directly to the ComboBox as it's inside a datatemplate, so I tought up update the binded value (Edit.ProtLevel):

```
// Test
Edit.ProtLevel = 5;
```

But the combobox doesn't update itself, which means that the selected items doesn't change. What's wrong?

Comment: What is `Edit.ProtLevel`? It should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or be a `DependencyProperty` to update the binding when changed.

Comment: It's just an int property of my inner class Edit and, currently, it does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I will try to fix it

Comment: It's ok to it be an int property, but the `Edit` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notify when `ProtLevel` changes.

Comment: Avoid binding to a Dictionary. Use the ObservableCollection. Manipulations of the ObservableCollection (or any collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged) will be immediately reflected in the ItemsControl. Dictionary does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged and therefore will not propagate any changes. That's all one can say. The posted snippets don't show what's going on. Post complete classes and methods that provide enough information of the context. If your code failes then provide a minimal example that  replicates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your binding to work correctly, the bound property should be a `DependencyProperty` or be inside of a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, something like this should work:

```
public class Edit : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private int _protLevel;

    public int ProtLevel {
        get => _protLevel;
        set {
            if (_protLevel != (_protLevel = value)) {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ProtLevel)));
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

You can read the [binding documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0).

And a simple `INotifyPropertyChanged` [implementation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).